Type Mismatch while using FlatFileItemReader BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper from String to Date
I am trying to batch process a file which has date field. Now when I fetch Date field using FlatFileItemReader it comes as a String.
I am trying to map it to following entity
@Entity
@Data
public class Customers {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "customer_name")
    private String customer_name;
    
    @Column(name="created_at", nullable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date createdAt;
    
    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        createdAt = new Date();
    }
    
}

My File is having values like
"id","customer_name","created_at"
1,Customer1,"2024-07-06 22:51:31"
2,Customer2,"2024-07-06 22:51:31"
3,Customer3,"2024-07-06 22:51:31"
4,Customer4,"2024-07-06 22:51:31"
5,Customer5,"2024-07-06 22:51:31"
6,Customer6,"2024-07-06 22:51:31"
7,Customer7,"2024-07-06 22:51:31"
8,Customer8,"2024-07-06 22:51:31"
9,Customer9,"2024-07-06 22:51:31"
10,Customer10,"2024-07-06 22:51:31"
Here is my reader
@Bean
    FlatFileItemReader<Customers> reader(){
        FlatFileItemReader<Customers> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/customers.csv"));
        itemReader.setName("customerReader");
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        itemReader.setLineMapper(linemapper());
        return itemReader;
    }
    private LineMapper<Customers> linemapper(){
        DefaultLineMapper<Customers> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
        lineTokenizer.setNames("id","customer_name","createdAt");
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Customers> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Customers.class);
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        return lineMapper;
    }

I am getting following error
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 3 in resource=[file [D:\projects\springmvc\connectionpooling\src\main\resources\customers.csv]], input=[1,Customer1,"2024-07-06 22:51:31"]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:198) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:182) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.lambda$provide$0(SimpleChunkProvider.java:132) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:369) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:206) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:388) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:312) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:255) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:261) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'target' on field 'createdAt': rejected value [2024-07-06 22:51:31]; codes [typeMismatch.target.createdAt,typeMismatch.createdAt,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.createdAt,createdAt]; arguments []; default message [createdAt]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'createdAt'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'createdAt': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.java:186) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:42) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:194) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

Is there somehow we can typcast one field to Date in FlatFileItemReader before mapping
